# Classical guitar to a mic to a guitar processor (or even better guitar amp)?

Tags: microphone, amplifier, guitar, setup

I would like to use a mic to amplify my classical guitar as I'm told it's the best way to do it without altering the guitar and losing some sound acoustically (with piezo, fishman....). However I also need an "electric" guitar sound.

I am certain that if I connect my classical guitar to my electric guitar amp, or even a guitar processor I can get the tone I'm looking for.

I think I could use 1 mic and an A/B pedal, A would be classical, and B would be "electric" (though I would use them both at the same time for "electric" sound).

So the whole point is to get the most natural sounding classical (without installing anything that physically touches it and/or alters it acoustically), and the ability to connect it to a guitar amp or processor (preferably amp).

All thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you want to do is a bit tricky. 
Lets take it from the top and clear some basics.

If you use a normal microphone driving it straight  to the  amplifier wont be a good option. 
Microphone 's output  impedance  is 600ohm opposed  to the 10kohm (hi-z) that the guitar amp is waiting for  at the input.

So to cover the microphone part you would need a mic preamplifier to amplify  the initial signal and then a re-amp box to make it hi-z so the amplifier can actually use it.

Now an amplifier has no broblem doing his job and giving you whatever sounds you're after, but judged by the case you may be into some trouble.

What i mean by trouble : a classical guitar is made to be a vibrant instrument as opposed to a solid one with a jack. The most common problems that arises in situations alike is feedback.  Lots of it,  uncontrollable loud feedback!

Also the sustain the body provides (which acts like a natural speaker) to the intonation will make the signal a bit constant and boomy losing detail and clarity.

Moreover,  you should keep in mind that a guitar amp pretty much drops the highs an the lows,  it just keeps the mids given the absence of a twitter.

You will be sending a midrange full signal(not a picky metal string edgy one) to a midrange speaker.

Bottom line is,  i dont think thats any close to being a best practice scenario, but over the years ive experimented with various similar ideas.  While sometimes it was an absolute  failure, some others it was just what it needed, but at all times this is experimental.

If you want a good stable solution id recommend buying a high end piezo,  i've had good luck with schertler http://www.schertler.com/en_IT/shop/pickups but they are a bit pricey too.

Good thing is that they provide a blue-tac style thingy that hooks it up to anything that produces sound without altering the instrument.

Classical instruments are not made to pass through amplifiers,  they are just made to produce an end product sound and fill a nice sounding room with music! . (imho)

Good luck!

Comment: The comments on feedback are absolutely true. It will liking make this idea untenable, not to mention that it will sound nothing like an electric guitar.